# High %wa from top command while runing PyTorch

Tags: linux, hard-drive, io

Everything was fine yesterday, but I noticed high dataloading time this morning. How do I go about trying to figure out how to fix this?

top:
[image: top]

process state:
[image: process state]

iotop:
[image: iotop]

iostat:
[image: iostat]

Comment: You fix this with faster storage. That is all.

Comment: Thank you! But I have two servers happen to become this suddenly, its weird. One of the server happened before, but it somehow fixed.